# .NET Web Service -- New Methods not appearing

Tags: .net, web-services

Building a test web service and all was working great, so I added the rest of my methods and now they aren't appearing in the "View in Browser" test page.

I stopped the service in the system tray.  Did a CLEAN.  Did Rebuild.  Did Build. Tried all these several times.

Odd thing is that one of my new methods replaced one of the old methods (HelloWorld default), but the rest of the 10 - 15 methods just aren't there.

Any ideas on this at all?

EDIT:  Here's a sample of what I've got...

```
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet GetSiteMap()
    {
        return Photo_DA.GetSitemap();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet GetByTypeDate(string photoType, DateTime photoDate)
    {
        return Photo_DA.GetByTypeDate(photoType, photoDate);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static DataSet GetArchiveCombos()
    {
        return Photo_DA.GetArchiveCombos();
    }
```

The first two show.  The third does not.

DOH!  STATIC is the bad guy -- I cannot delete this message, so Admin can I suppose.

Comment: No need to delete, it's still a valid question.  Add your discovery as an answer and accept it so people finding your question in the future might not have to go what you went through =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should `GetArchiveCombos()` really be static?

Comment: Nope and that was what I figured out... giving you the cred though!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to apply the attribute [WebMethod] to your new methods?

Comment: ooh ouch. can you provide the declaration for one of your web methods?

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the web reference?

Comment: Also stop the service host and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any new endpoints that need to be configured in your web.config file?